# How to use Room Database in Android with Bazel?

Tags: java, android, android-room, bazel

I have lots of SQLite tables that has now become hard to manage at the app side because of multiple DAO classes. I am using Bazel as my build system but I can't figure out how to use Room DB with Bazel build system.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Maven artifact resolver like [rules_jvm_external](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external/), it'll look something like this.

In your `WORKSPACE` file, add the dependency on the Room compiler:

```py
load("@rules_jvm_external//:specs.bzl", "maven")

maven_install(
    name = "maven",
    artifacts = [
        "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha04",
        "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0-alpha04",
        "com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android",
        maven.artifact("com.google.auto", "auto-common", "0.10", neverlink = True),
        # .. other artifacts
    ],
    repositories = [
        "https://maven.google.com",
        "https://jcenter.bintray.com",
    ],
)
```

In a `BUILD` file (e.g. `<project root>/BUILD`), create the `java_plugin` target to expose the annotation processor for Room:

```py
java_plugin(
    name = "androidx_room_room_compiler_plugin",
    processor_class = "androidx.room.RoomProcessor",
    deps = ["@maven//:androidx_room_room_compiler"],
    neverlink = True,
)

java_library(
    name = "androidx_room_room_compiler_library",
    exports = [
        "@maven//:androidx_room_room_compiler",
    ],
    exported_plugins = [
        ":androidx_room_room_compiler_plugin"
    ],
)
```

Finally, in your app's `BUILD` file, depend on the Room compiler and runtime:

```
android_library(
    name = "lib_prod",
    # ...
    deps = [
        "@maven//:androidx_room_room_runtime",
        "//:androidx_room_room_compiler_library",
    ],
)
```

I have ported an Android sample app that uses the Room and Lifecycle libraries to build with Bazel here: https://github.com/jin/BasicRxJavaSample-Bazel

Comment: Hi Jin, did you try running it? It is giving me import errors. Here is what my [WORKSPACE](https://pastebin.com/YfTSaZva) files looks like. This is my [<project root>/BUILD](https://pastebin.com/CJRe0r63) and [app's BUILD](https://pastebin.com/XrXWut4t). I am doing exactly same but still not able to figure out why it is not able to import roomDB packages.

Comment: It looks like your `android_binary` isn't depending on        "@maven//:androidx_room_room_runtime" and "//:androidx_room_room_compiler_library" in its `deps` attribute.

Comment: Also, consider using rules_jvm_external to fetch gson, volley, and the other android support libraries. `gmaven_rules` is no longer supported.

Comment: Currently I am on Bazel 0.15, do I have to upgrade it to get the support for RoomDB and rules_jvm_external? I also tried adding `@maven//:androidx_room_room_runtime` and `//:androidx_room_room_compiler_library` to my `android_binary` deps but still not able to get it work :(

Comment: Unlikely, but Bazel 0.15 is really old, so you should upgrade if you can. Can you elaborate more about what is not working exactly?

Comment: Hi Jin, sorry for late reply. So, this is what my new [app's BUILD](https://pastebin.com/aakq3iSV) looks like.  WORKSPACE and  <project root>/BUILD are same. I added `@maven//:androidx_room_room_runtime` and `//:androidx_room_room_compiler_library` to `deps` of `android_binary` and I am getting this error while running Bazel Build command,

Comment: `no such package '@maven//': type 'repository_ctx' has no method report_progress(string) and referenced by '//SenANPR:senanpr'` and `Analysis of target '//SenANPR:senanpr' failed; build aborted: no such package '@maven//': type 'repository_ctx' has no method report_progress(string)`. Can you please help me out with this?

Comment: That looks like you are using an older Bazel version. Please update to the latest version, if you can.

Comment: Hi Jin, just update my bazel to 0.24.1. Now again I was trying to import RoomDB and I got this [Exception](https://pastebin.com/bd1zHB7z).

Comment: I updated the `maven_install` snippet in the answer. Could you try that please?

Comment: I updated my WORKSPACE file, and I got a new [Exception](https://pastebin.com/c4rp2g05). It says `Ljava/util/stream/Collector; strictly requires --min-sdk-version >= 24 (blocked at current API level 13)` but I have set min api to 26 in Android Manifest and also while configuring tensorflow workspace.

Comment: Hi Jin, Can you please help me out with this? I would be really thankful. :)

Comment: Could you please file an issue for this on https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external? I suspect that this may be an issue with either Bazel's android rules or maven_install.

Comment: @sonudelhikkc I've updated the answer with a port of an Android app using Room to build with Bazel here: https://github.com/jin/BasicRxJavaSample-Bazel

Comment: Thanks. I'll check this out.